# Primefaces 5 fileUpload handler not called

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I'm developing a Web Project with JSF and PrimeFaces 5.0. Although there are many forums about this problem I can't find the solution with the FileUpload. The issue is that when I Uplaod a file handler method is never invoked

This is my code:

**HTML page:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <f:view>
            <p:panel id="panel" header="Registros de Fuente" style="width:100%;">

                <h:form enctype="multipart-data">
                    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{registrosBean.handleFileUpload}"
                                    required="true" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
                                    multiple="true" sizeLimit="1000000" fileLimit="5" update="messages"
                                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx)$/">
                    </p:fileUpload>
                </h:form>

                <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p:fileUpload value="#{registrosBean.file}" mode="simple" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false"/>
                </h:form>
            </p:panel>
        </f:view>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

**BEAN:**

```java
@Component("registrosBean")
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class RegistroBean extends GenericBean<Registrofuente> implements Serializable {

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        System.out.println("SOME CONSOLE MESSAGE");
    }

    public void cogerArchivos( ) {
        System.out.println("SOME CONSOLE MESSAGE");
    }

    public UploadedFile file;

    /**
     * @return the file
     */
    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    /**
     * @param file the file to set
     */
    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        System.out.println("SOME CONSOLE MESSAGE");
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

**web.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  <display-name>UNAC</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>aristo</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>pages/login.jsf</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
            <param-value>10240</param-value> <!-- 10 Mb -->
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Some aditional information about my project

- JSF 2.1
- IDE: Eclipse
- Jboss 7.1

It's important to say that I've already added the commons-io and commons-fileupload libraries to the WEB-INF\lib folder

I've been many days and consulted many forums about this issue and I can not find the solution, any suggestion will help. Thank you

Comment: why do you have growl inside the fileUpload ?

Comment: I just removed the growl message, thanks

Comment: Might be related to the use of spring ? Remove `@Component`, and rewrite the EL in the `fileUploadListener` attribute correctly.

Comment: I just removed the `@Component` annotation and nothing happend, I changed the annotations to:
`@ViewScoped`
`@ManagedBean(name = "registrosBean")`

Answer (score 0):

try to simplify the filter on web.xml first. Try this.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

And you don't need those commons-io libs on WEB-INF\lib since you are using PF5 already. Remove them.